# Listing Schema Locks on SDE from arcpy

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, enterprise-geodatabase, schema-locks

In ArcGIS Pro, if you right-click on a .sde file > Administration > Locks, you see a list of feature classes that currently have an active lock.

Is it possible to get this list via Python, such as arcpy module?

I know you can use `arcpy.ListUsers()` to identify active user connections to the SDE, but I cannot find an equivalent for locks. I use `arcpy.TestSchemaLocks()` regularly but this only specifies whether a lock exists, & not any info regarding lock, i.e. user, session id etc.

Comment: I'm removing ArcGIS Python API from your question: This would require arcpy, and the ArcGIS Python API would simply wrap anything from arcpy (should anything in arcpy exist)

Comment: @KHibma arcpy & the ArcGIS Python API are separate modules, while they have some overlaps, they are not the same.

Comment: I know what they are. And I'm saying you wont find the answer to your question in the ArcGIS Python API. I'm trying to help focus your question. If you don't think my edit was helpful, you can revert it back.